# $Env variable not recognized inside an if block

Tags: powershell

I am trying to execute this code, which just basically copies a file from over the network to the local logged on user's desktop if it is older than the one on the network. The first line of the following code works well, but it throws an error for the part where `$env:userprofile` is used inside an if block. No idea what's going on here.

```
Copy-Item -Path "\\path1\subpath1\subpath2\Patch\help\*" -Filter *.chm -Destination "$Env:UserProfile\Desktop" -force -Recurse

$chmfileNetwork = Get-ItemPropertyvalue -Path 'path1\subpath1\subpath2\Patch\help\*' -Filter *.chm -Name 'LastWriteTime'

$chmfileLocal = Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path '$Env:UserProfile\Desktop\*' -Filter *.chm -Name 'LastWriteTime'

if ($chmfileLocal -lt $chmfileNetwork) {
    Copy-Item -Path "path1\subpath1\subpath2\Patch\help\*" -Destination "$Env:UserProfile\Desktop" -force -Recurse
} else {
    echo "Saul good, man"
}
```

That throws the error

```
Get-ItemPropertyValue : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name '$Env'
does not exist.
At C:\Users\user1\Downloads\PS2EXE-GUI\psfile.ps1:28 char:17
+ ... fileLocal = Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path '$Env:UserProfile\Desktop\*'  ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: ($Env:String) [Get-ItemPropertyValue], DriveNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DriveNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetItemPropertyValueCommand
```

Comment: try `$home\Desktop` instead

Comment: Thanks TheMadTechnician, will try now and let you know if that works.

Comment: Hey, that works. Thank you very much. Can you add that as an answer please?

Comment: `'$Env:UserProfile\Desktop\*'` -> `"$Env:UserProfile\Desktop\*"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `$home\Desktop` to get a user's desktop folder, but Ansgar Wiechers really pointed out the problem with your script as to why it was throwing the error. You used single quotes on the `chmfileLocal =` line. Variables are not expanded when you use single quotes, only when you use double quotes. The original script could have been fixed with the change of:

```
$chmfileLocal = Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path "$Env:UserProfile\Desktop\*" -Filter *.chm -Name 'LastWriteTime'
```

Comment: Thank you very much, TheMadTechnician and Ansgar Wiechars for this answer.